# How to combine array value with same key?

Tags: php, arrays

So i have this array that i get from query. The array look like this when i `print_r`

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Name] => NAME 1
            [Last] => LastValue1
            [Bid] => 
            [Ask] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Name] => NAME 1
            [Last] => 
            [Bid] => BidValue1
            [Ask] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Name 2
            [Last] => LastValue2
            [Bid] => BidValue2
            [Ask] =>
        )
    [3] => Array
    (
        [Name] => NAME 1
        [Last] => 
        [Bid] => 
        [Ask] => AskValue1
    )
    [4] => Array
    (
        [Name] =>Name 2
        [Last] => 
        [Bid] => 
        [Ask] => AskValue2
    )

)
```

and i want to achieve array looks like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Name] => NAME 1
            [Last] => LastValue1
            [Bid] => BidValue1
            [Ask] => AskValue1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Name 2
            [Last] => LastValue2
            [Bid] => BidValue2
            [Ask] => AskValue2
        )

)
```

I try this way (get it from google)

```
$result = array();
foreach ($newArray as $element) {
    $result[$element['Name']][] = $element;
}

echo "<pre>";print_r($result);
```

But it is not showing the result that i want. How can i achieve it ? 
thanks in advance and sorry for my english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below snippet for the same,

```
$result = [];
foreach ($newArray as $element) {
    foreach ($element as $key => $value) {
        // checking if value for key is already added to result array
        if ((!empty($result[$element['Name']]) && !array_key_exists($key, $result[$element['Name']])) || empty($result[$element['Name']])) {
            if (!empty($value)) { // checking if value not empty
                $result[$element['Name']] = ($result[$element['Name']] ?? []);
                // merge it to group wise name result array
                $result[$element['Name']] = array_merge($result[$element['Name']], [$key => $value]);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

[array_merge](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) — Merge one or more arrays
[array_key_exists](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) — Checks if the given key or index exists in the array

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/pb7PW)

**Output:-**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Name] => NAME1
            [Last] => LastValue1
            [Bid] => BidValue1
            [Ask] => AskValue1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Name2
            [Last] => LastValue2
            [Bid] => BidValue2
            [Ask] => AskValue2
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the shortest and simple solution by using `foreach` with `array_filter`

```
 foreach($a as &$v){
    $v = array_filter($v);
    isset($r[$v['Name']]) ? ($r[$v['Name']] +=  $v) : ($r[$v['Name']] = $v);
 }
```

You can use `array_values` to re arrange the order of array.

Working example : https://3v4l.org/XeQHa